# how to convert price from string to int in mongodb and pass it through $project

Tags: mongodb

here I am calculating count and price according to group by I am getting the count but price total is coming as 0. how to send price total .

```
 db.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(510);
        } else {
            var collection = db.get().collection('Order');
            collection.aggregate(
                [

                    {
                        "$match": {
                            "$and": [{
                                    "createdDate": {
                                        "$gte": dateFrom
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "createdDate": {
                                        "$lte": dateTo
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$project": {
                            createdDate: {
                                $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdDate" },

                            },
                            paymentType: "$paymentType",
                            price:"$price"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group": {
                            "_id": {
                                "createdDate": "$createdDate",
                                "paymentType": "$paymentType"
                            },
                            "COUNT(_id)": {"$sum": 1},
                            "TOTALPRICE": { "$sum" : "$price" }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$project": {
                            "COUNT": "$COUNT(_id)",
                            "TOTALPRICE" : "$TOTALPRICE",
                            "createdDate": "$_id.createdDate",
                            "paymentType": "$_id.paymentType",
                            "_id": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$sort": {
                            "createdDate": 1
                        }
                    }
                ], {
                    "allowDiskUse": true
                }
            )
```

query response is:
 COUNT: 1
TOTALPRICE: 0
createdDate: "2019-09-24"
paymentType: "cod"

TOTALPRICE is coming 0 which is 70.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `price` to the $projection step before the $group:

```
                    {
                        "$project": {
                            createdDate: {
                                $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdDate" },

                            },
                            paymentType: "$paymentType",
                            price: "$price"
                        }
                    }
```

Otherwise you're summing on a field that no longer exists due to the projection phase dropping it, hence the 0.

Comment: how to convert price from string to int in mongodb? I tried toInt but its not working

Comment: If you're using mongo version 4.0+ just use $toInt, otherwise you need to do it in code.

Comment: my mongodb version is 3